# Cookies written in JavaScript only display as integers in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

I'm having an issue with properly reading cookies in PHP, that were written in JavaScript. Specifically, the issue is that the PHP will read only integers, and ignore all other characters. For example, if I have 'firstName' stored as 'Bob', and 'phoneNumber' displayed as '555-1234', PHP will display 0 for 'firstName' and '555' for 'phoneNumber'.

Example data that I'm storing (cookieName=value)

```
AreCookiesEnabled=344
firstName=Bob
lastName=Smith
email=bsmith@email.com
hpID=PL7H88
company=Bobcorp
phoneNumber=555-1234
language=en
os=Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; CMNTDF; BRI/1; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
browser=5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; CMNTDF; BRI/1; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
description=This is a description.
```

This is the JavaScript function I'm using to write the cookies:

```
function SetCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, nDays)
{
    //alert("SetCookie("+cookieName+", "+cookieValue+", "+nDays+")");
    var today = new Date();
    var expire = new Date();
    if (nDays==null || nDays==0)
    {
        nDays=1;
    }

    if(cookieValue == '')
    {
        cookieValue = 'none';
    }

    expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
    document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue)+";expires="+expire.toGMTString()+";domain=.ourdomain.com;path=/";
}//
```

On the PHP page, I have phpinfo() displaying the cookies. For _REQUEST["firstName"] and _COOKIE["firstName"] I get "Bob", but when I echo $_COOKIE["firstName"] I get 0. In fact, using the example information from above, I get this output:

```
Are cookies enabled: 108
First Name: 0
Last Name: 0
Email: 0
HP ID: 0
Company: 0
Phone Number: 555
Language: 0
Operating System: 0
Browser: 5
Description: 0
```

I also do print_r($_COOKIE); and get this output:

```
Array ( [testsession] => true [firstName] => Bob [lastName] => Smith [email] => bsmith@email.com [hpID] => PL7H88 [company] => Bobcorp [phoneNumber] => 555-1234 [language] => en [AreCookiesEnabled] => 108 [description] => This is a description. [browser] => 5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; CMNTDF; BRI/1; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E) [os] => Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; CMNTDF; BRI/1; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E) )
```

It seems as if everything is there and correct, except in the final output. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Thank you.

**Edit:** By popular demand, this is the PHP file...

```
<?php
phpinfo();
phpversion();
print_r($_COOKIE);

echo("<p>An error has occurred.</p>");
echo("<p><b>Are cookies enabled:</b> ");
echo($_COOKIE['AreCookiesEnabled']+"<br /></p>");
echo("<p><b>First Name:</b> ");
echo($_COOKIE['firstName']+"<br /></p>");
echo("<p><b>Last Name:</b> ");
echo($_COOKIE['lastName']+"<br /></p>");
echo("<p><b>Email:</b> ");
echo($_COOKIE['email']+"<br /></p>");
echo("<p><b>HP ID:</b> ");
echo($_COOKIE['hpID']+"<br /></p>");
echo("<p><b>Company:</b> ");
echo($_COOKIE['company']+"<br /></p>");
echo("<p><b>Phone Number:</b> ");
echo($_COOKIE['phoneNumber']+"<br /></p>");
echo("<p><b>Language:</b> ");
echo($_COOKIE['language']+"<br /><br /></p>");
echo("<p><b>Operating System:</b> ");
echo($_COOKIE['os']+"<br /></p>");
echo("<p><b>Browser:</b> ");
echo($_COOKIE['browser']+"<br /><br /></p>");
echo("<p><b>Description:</b> <br /><br />");
echo($_COOKIE['description']+"</p>");
?>
```

Comment: Would help to see the PHP code you have to output those cookies, but my first instinct says you have a `+` somewhere in the code where you should have a `.`, which could be forcing the string value to an integer.

Comment: Piggybacking on @RossMcLellan's comment I'd guess from your output that you're doing things like echo `"First Name: " + $_COOKIE...`

Comment: I've updated with the PHP file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is obviously not in the session data itself, it's how you get it in PHP.

The behavior I'm seeing here is that those strings ("Bob" and "555-1234") are being converted to int. PHP in fact convert those strings to `0` and `555` respectively as described [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion).

In particular:

> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string
>   starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used.
>   Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero).

Check your script for int casting (defined as `(int)`) or any implicit conversion and remove it. Or post your PHP code and let me check it.

Edit:

In your PHP code you are using the `+` operator, which is reserved for numeric values; therefore leading to an implicit conversion to int. Use `.` for string concatenation instead.

Comment: You were right! I forgot that PHP uses a . instead of a + to concatenate strings. Silly n00b mistake. Thank you!